# C# Masked Text Box Border

Tags: c#, border, maskedtextbox

I'd like to display a red border around my masked text box when the user enters incorrect values, but there isn't a border setting for a masked text box. Does anyone have any workarounds for this?

As always, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Put the textbox inside a panel and set the border of the panel, and set the Dock of the textbox to Fill.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little less of a hack than that, but I appreciate the input regardless. I may have to do this if there's no other way.

Comment: If you have a lot of controls like that, you can make a user control, that simply exposes all the attributes you want.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific? I'm not too familiar with these data types. You have a link I can do some reading at perhaps?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charles_sterling/archive/2007/12/04/how-to-add-and-create-a-usercontrol-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx